# FileNotFoundException in Android Studio, but works fine in browser

Tags: android, https, download, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to connect to a website to receive some JSON information.  When I run the app in Android Studio using a connected Nexus 7 device I get a java.io.FileNotFound exception, but if I click on the name of the file that was not found, the response expected immediately shows in my browser. This is a new app for me, but I have done similar things in the past that have worked. I have been trying multiple things over the last 2 days and just can't seem to find the problem. Code blows up when I call connection.getInputStream().  All of this is running in an AsyncTask.

**My Code**

```
public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
    // urlSpec: https://api.weather.gov/points/48.0174,-115.2278

    try {
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connection ioe: " + ioe.toString());
        Toast.makeText(context, "@string/can_not_connect",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream(); *** Blows up here ****

        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connection Response code: " + 
                  connection.getResponseMessage());
        }

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
04-02 15:40:59.693 32471-32495/com.drme.weathertest E/WeatherFetcher: Failed 
 to fetch items
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.weather.gov/points/48.0174,-115.2278 
*** Note that if I click on this file name, it works in my browser ***
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)       
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)   
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    at com.drme.weatherNoaa.WeatherFetcher.getUrlBytes(WeatherFetcher.java:148)
    at com.drme.weatherNoaa.WeatherFetcher.getUrlString(WeatherFetcher.java:183)
    at com.drme.weatherNoaa.WeatherFetcher.downloadGridPoints(WeatherFetcher.java:202)
    at com.drme.weatherNoaa.WeatherFetcher.requestForecast(WeatherFetcher.java:262)
    at com.drme.weatherNoaa.WeatherFragment$SearchTask.doInBackground(WeatherFragment.java:329)
    at com.drme.weatherNoaa.WeatherFragment$SearchTask.doInBackground(WeatherFragment.java:296)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of this webservice?

Comment: Selvin - Yes I did, but I am embarrassed that I seemed to gloss over some if it since some other sites did not have the same requirements.  See my answer to my own question.

Comment: Well, It is written that you need to include two specific headers in the request...

Comment: Selvin - Well, it just seemed so easy when I typed the api access string into the browser, everything worked great.  I "assumed" that I could duplicate the browser strings in my code and it would work OK.

Comment: you should rather test it with something like curl or fiddler which sends "plain" request ...

Comment: Selvin - Thanks for the suggestion.  I will look into curl and/or fiddler.

Comment: I'm a little disappointed that the question was voted down.  I may have missed some things when I RTFM, but I struggled with this for two days before asking the question.   Before this I had never heard of Request Headers, much less had to use them. All the other web requests I have used just embedded keys and such in the actual request.  I was not seeing the problem and was just looking for suggestions.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional reading of webservice documentation (some of it seems a little thin to me) and some additional posts on the web, the answer is that they require Acceptance and User-agent headers in the request.  I have made these changes and the code now works as desired.

**New static constants**

```
private static final String ACCEPT_PROPERTY = "application/geo+json;version=1";
private static final String USER_AGENT_PROPERTY = "xxxx.com (xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com)";
```

**Code changes**

```
 connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", ACCEPT_PROPERTY);  // added
 connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT_PROPERTY); // added
```

No other changes were required, although it took me awhile to figure out how to add the headers and what their format might be.

Thanks for checking this out.

Comment: are you sure that version should be header? I think that it should be `Accept: application/geo+json;version=1` ... also as user agent you should rather send your app name (and maybe version)

Comment: Selvin - I will change the Accept header to your suggestion.  The way they talked about the Version, I thought I could use a Version property.  They specify that the User-Agent string can be anything, but if you include contact information (website or email) they can contact you if your string is associated with a security event.  The User-agent will be replaced with an API key in the future.  Thanks for pointing these thing out.  I have never had to deal with these headers before.